# Is there a better way to do this? Extracting numbers

Tags: c

I need to extract all the digits of a 16 digit number and need to store the as all different values, but I am repeating a lot of code. Is there a better way to do this?

it worked but I want to make it look nicer. I am a complete noob

```
int num1 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num2 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num3 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num4 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num5 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num6 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num7 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num8 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num9 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num10 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num11 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num12 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num13 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num14 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num15 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
int num16 = creditn % 10;
creditn /= 10;
```

Comment: Do you know about loops and arrays?

Comment: I don't know how to make a loop that saves diffrent integers with different names, its for a school project and I havent learned about arrays yet

Comment: *diffrent integers with different names* - is a good candidate to be an array

Comment: If nothing else, this is a very nice "teachable moment".  Using 16 different variables `num1`, `num2`, ... is clearly wasteful and unnecessarily repetitive.  How can I have 16 related variables, where I can use some other variable (like `i`) that selects whether I want `num1` or `num2` or one of the other ones?  That is a very real need, and it's precisely the need that motivates a most useful programming concept: the array!

Comment: _I haven't learned about arrays yet_ - Perhaps this assignment is the segue into them and you're supposed to do it as you have, so tomorrow you can contrast how arrays are so much better?

Comment: Often times the initial assignments you are given will expect you to do stuff like this, _without_ arrays or the like. Annoying, but I wouldn't worry about it. You at least realize there's a smarter way. +1

Comment: FWIW, this question seem to be related to the infamous CS50 credit card assignment. As I stress every time I see it, the number should be read and treated as *string* not as an integer. This will greatly simplify things.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well-spotted!

Comment: Yes, there's a better way. Extract one digit (rightmost) and deal with it as needed. Then, extract the next digit and deal with it as needed. The problem does not require you to separately store each of the 16 digits at one time. The solution to this problem does not need an array (that would present its own set of challenges.)

Answer (score 1):

As you could see, doing this without arrays is painful.

You probably need something like this:

```
int num[16];  // declare an array of 16 numbers,
              // rather than 16 variables num1 to num16

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
  num[i] = credit % n;
  credit /= n;
}
```

Comment: Note to OP: the digits will be in reverse order.

Comment: @jarmod right, but there should be something left to do for the OP.

Comment: Yes, no issues there. Just alerting the OP.